# how to replace cell values in HTML table with image and display the value as tooltip for same cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need help in achieving below task. 
i'm reading a XML file and based on the values present in that XML, iam creating a HTML page with table using jquery.

But now after creating table, i need to replace the cell value of tables with image.  i.e  if the cell value is Y then it should be replaced with one image. If the value is other than Y then it should be replace with another icon.

My code to create table dynamically is as follows is there any way to modify below code to validate the input and create the final HTML directly: and after creating table with images, i want to display cell value as a tool tip for repective cell.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "input.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      $(xml).find('Envs').each(function() {
        var nodeinfo = $(this).find('Node').text(),
          http = $(this).find('HTTP').text(),
          webs = $(this).find('WEBS').text(),
          mq = $(this).find('MQ').text(),
          td = "",
          tdc = "";
        $('#doclib').append("" + td + nodeinfo + tdc + td + http + tdc + td + webs + tdc + td + mq + tdc + "")
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Show us some markup, and the jQuery you have so far.

Comment: can you post your code and a js fiddle?

Comment: please post the code.

Comment: In you **creating a HTML page with table using jquery** function, you should check for the value you receive, and then while creating the `td` you insert the image.

Comment: Yes. i'm not able to do that with my code. Can you tell me what change is required to do that ?? I have posted that code in below answer section